# Introducir un filtro con varias condiciones, en una función en R

Tags: r, funciones, sintaxis, filtros-css

Estoy armando una función para analizar la base de datos de la Encuesta Nacional de Nutrición y Salud 2018-2019 (Ennys2) y tengo dos dudas puntuales, en relación con los avances del código:

1. No logro identificar qué error de sintaxis tengo, porque me devuelve 0 como resultado
2. Necesitaría armar 3 grupos de condiciones para el segundo filtro, probé con case_when y ifelse, pero no funcionan tampoco.

---

```
ennys2_FCA <- ennys2_FCA %>%  
rename(tipo_cuestionario = E_CUEST,
     ponderador = F_STG_calib,
     "leche, yogur y quesos 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_1,
     "frutas 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_2,
     "verduras 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_3,
     "carne roja 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_7,
     "pescado 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_8,
     "bebidas artificiales con azúcar 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_16,
     "facturas y pastelería 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_13,
     "golosinas 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_12,
     "productos de copetín 2-12 años" = T_C2_FCA_6_1_11,
     "leche, yogur y quesos 13-17 años"= T_C3_FCA_6_1_1,
     "frutas 13-17 años"  = T_C3_FCA_6_1_2,
     "verduras 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_3,
     "carne roja 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_7,
     "pescado 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_8,
     "bebidas artificiales con azúcar 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_16,
     "facturas y pastelería 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_13,
     "golosinas 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_12,
     "productos de copetín 13-17 años" = T_C3_FCA_6_1_11,
     "leche, yogur y quesos 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_1,
     "frutas 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_2,
     "verduras 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_3,
     "carne roja 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_7,
     "pescado 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_8,
     "bebidas artificiales con azúcar 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_16,
     "facturas y pastelería 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_13,
     "golosinas 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_12,
     "productos de copetín 18 y más años" = T_C4_FCA_6_1_11
)

FCA_resumen <- function(variable_respuesta)
  {
  resultado <- ennys2_FCA %>%
    filter({{variable_respuesta}} != " ") %>%
    group_by({{variable_respuesta}}) %>%
    summarise(FCA = sum(ponderador)) %>%
    mutate(porc_FCA = round(FCA / sum(FCA) * 100, 1)) %>%
    filter(
    {{variable_respuesta}} == "1 vez al dÃ­a" | 
    {{variable_respuesta}} == "Entre 2 y 3 veces al dÃ­a" | 
    {{variable_respuesta}} == "Entre 4 y 5 veces al dÃ­a"| 
    {{variable_respuesta}} == "6 veces o mÃ¡s por dÃ­a") %>% 
    summarise(!!paste ("consumo al menos una vez al día de",{{variable_respuesta}} ) := sum(porc_FCA))
  return(resultado)
}
   
resultado_cuestionario <- FCA_resumen(variable_respuesta = "frutas 2-12 años")
print(resultado_cuestionario)
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Acabo de descargarme el CSV pero no encuentro que exista una variable llamada por ejemplo `frutas 2-12 años`

Comment: Seleccione las variables de frecuencia de consumo y las renombré. La siguiente correspode a "frutas 2-12 años": T_C2_FCA_6_1_2. Agregué el código donde realicé la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una alternativa para realizar esta operación es tratar de aislar las variables que quieres analizar, y cambiar el nombre dentro de la función. En este caso, renombre la variable respuesta como x, y el código funcionó. En este caso, reduje un poco el segundo filter, y coloque la data fuera de la función, en el caso que tengas otro archivo con iguales parametros, y asi no tienes que cambiar la función, de lo contrario puedes cambiar data por ennys2_FCA y también funciona.

```
> FCA_resumen <- function(data, variable_respuesta){
+   
+   resultado <- data %>%
+     select(x = {{ variable_respuesta }}, ponderador) %>%
+     filter(x != " ") %>%
+     group_by(x) %>%
+     summarise(FCA = sum(ponderador)) %>%
+     mutate(porc_FCA = round(FCA / sum(FCA) * 100, 1)) %>%
+     filter(x %in% c("1 vez al día", 
+                     "Entre 2 y 3 veces al día", 
+                     "Entre 4 y 5 veces al día",
+                     "6 veces o más por día")) %>%
+     summarise(!!paste("consumo al menos una vez al día de", quo_name(variable_respuesta)) := sum(porc_FCA))
+   
+   return(resultado)
+ }


> FCA_resumen(ennys2_FCA, variable_respuesta = "frutas 2-12 años")
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  `consumo al menos una vez al día de frutas 2-12 años`
                                                  <dbl>
1                                                  36.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces algo como esto `group_by({{variable_respuesta}})` en el ámbito de `tidyverse` estas usando una técnica conocida como indirección, que es muy útil, cuando trabajas con funciones, el tema es que no lo estás usando adecuadamente. Principalmente hay ciertas funciones como `filter()` dónde la indirección no funciona como lo esperas, esto : `filter({{variable}} != " ")` no funciona, la indirección en este caso es a nivel de la condición completa, es decir `filter({{condición}})`, y por cierto, con el `mutate()` pasa algo parecido.

Mi reescritura de tu función podría ser algo así:

```
FCA_resumen <- function(data, variable)
{
  data %>% 
    select(variable = {{variable}}, ponderador) %>% 
    filter(variable != " ") %>%
    mutate(al_menos_una_vez = variable %in% c("1 vez al día", 
                                              "Entre 2 y 3 veces al día",
                                              "Entre 4 y 5 veces al día", 
                                              "6 veces o más por día")) %>% 
    summarise(porcentaje = sum(ponderador*al_menos_una_vez)/sum(ponderador))
}
```

Lo primero que hacemos es `select(variable = {{variable}}, ponderador)` que tiene como objetivo, solo quedarnos con las columnas que necesitamos y renombrar la columna/variable referenciad por `{{variable}}` como `variable` y luego simplemente usamos ese nombre.

Comentarios adicionales:

- Fijte que no uso un `group_by()` ya que es más sencillo hacer una sumarización condicional, cuando hago: `sum(ponderador*al_menos_una_vez)/sum(ponderador))`
- No es necesario salvar en una variable y hacer un `return`, en R lo último que evalúa una función es el valor de retorno
- Es conveniente para hacer más generica la función, que reciba el `data.frame` de entrada.
- No es necesario pasar la variable con las dobles comillas, la indirección, justamente permite usar el nombre de la columna al estilo de `tidyverse` ocurre que en tu caso, los nombres de columna no están normalizados, lo cual no es una buena práctica, por lo que no ganas mucho, pero la idea es que podrías llamar a la función así:

  ```
    FCA_resumen(ennys2_FCA, variable = `frutas 2-12 años`)
  ```

  o si la columna estuviera normalizada

  ```
    FCA_resumen(ennys2_FCA, variable = frutas_2_12)
  ```